Find occurrence of transport status
I have 2 Tables "Transport_Status" and "Receipts" where the id number is the key and can occur in Transport_Status more than once.
I want to protocol the transmission of the Receipts
Only if a 200 code does not appear, show the resulting set (Show only results with Error code 900)
What I have is:
Select * from Transport_Protocoll 
inner join Receipts on Transport_Protocoll.id=Receipts.id
where not exists(select * where TRANSPORT_STATUS=200)

But I still receive the results from the 900 Error even when TRANSPORT_STATUS=200 exists
Transport_Protocolls:



ID
Transport_Status
Transport_Detail
Date




1111126
900
Network is unreachable (connect failed)
10.07.2024


1111126
200
receipt send successfully
14.07.2024


1111127
900
Network is unreachable (connect failed)
10.07.2024



Reiceipts:



ID
order_date
article
Date




1111126
1.07.2024
Ice Cream
10.07.2024


1111127
1.01.2024
Yogurt
03.07.2024


1111128
1.05.2024
Bogey Man
03.07.2024



Expected result:



ID
Transport_Status
Transport_Detail
Date




1111127
900
Network is unreachable (connect failed)
10.07.2024


1111128
null
null)
null



Because receipt with Id 1111126 failed at some point but was afterwards send successfully.
And 1111127 was not successfully in any other point

You might get better answers if you provide some sample and expected query data

on id=id.  Can't you make a better reference like on tp.id = r.id?  Of course you need to alias your tables.

You dont have a table name in your exists

Select * from Transport_Protocoll as tp join Receipts as r on tp.id=r.id where not exists (select 1 from Transport_Protocoll as tp2 where tp2.id=tp.id and tp2.Transport_Status=200)

It worked @Nathan_Sav thanks a lot.
So the "select 1" statement was the key?!

And having a table name to check in the exists too

@Nathan_Sav is it also possible to get the id: 1111128 where there is no entry in the Transport Protocol Table?
Please note the expected result Table

Yes, something using not exists (select 1 from Transport_Protocoll as tp2 where tp2.id=tp.id)

You want Receipts transmission protocol status.
So, first take table Receipts and LEFT JOIN Transport_Protocols. And result contain rows from table Receipts,  where there is no entry in the Transport Protocol table.
See example
Select r.ID, t.Transport_Status,t.Transport_Detail,t.Date  
from Receipts r
left join Transport_Protocols t on t.id=r.id
where not exists
  (select 1 from Transport_Protocols t2 
   where t2.id=t.id and TRANSPORT_STATUS=200
  )

Output



ID
Transport_Status
Transport_Detail
Date




1111127
900
Network is unreachable (connect failed)
2024-07-10


1111128
null
null
null



demo
